# animate method function performs unexpected delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following piece of code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showmenu").click(function() {
        $(".menu").animate({width: "toggle"}, {duration: 1000});
    });
});
</script>

...

<div id="showmenu"><a href="#">Hide/Show Menu</a></div>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>My</li>
        <li>Handsome</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the menu is hidden, the animation performs immediately. *This is the expected behavior*. But when the menu is visible, there is a delay of 1 second - the `duration` parameter, actually - before the animation gets executed.

How could I remove this delay? Is there something bad with my code?

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/dwq26xf6/

Comment: There is no delay before the animation starts: http://jsfiddle.net/dwq26xf6/1/

Comment: Wolff says that you should add a ```width``` to your menu.

Comment: Ok I figured it out thanks to A. Wolff and mirceapop; my menu was actually bigger than expected and there was no delay, indeed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad : this is simply the length of your elements that are too big! See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dwq26xf6/.

You should then adapt the width to your content! For example :

```
div {
    display : inline-block;
}
```

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/dwq26xf6/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You don't have to specify duration as like this `{duration: 1000}` , below is the corrected code and set the duration to some small value;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showmenu").click(function() {
        $(".menu").animate({width: "toggle"},100);
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwq26xf6/3/)

Comment: Take a look at A.Wolff's comment.

Comment: it's better not to have `animation` for `width` rather than have the `animation` but can't be seen clearly